# How to count elements in TinyXml?

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, tinyxml

I think problem is with wrong using function or something else.

This part of code is working but the result isn't well.

```
TiXmlElement* e = hDoc.FirstChildElement().Element(); // think problem is there
while (e)
{
    e = e->NextSiblingElement();  //or may be there
    count++;
}
```

The result of count is 1.

---

Xml file is:

```
<doc>
   <state> ... </state>
   <state> ... </state>
   ...
</doc>
```

Can't find work example.

Comment: What "isn't well" about the result? What result do you get and what result do you expect?

Comment: Then either delete the question or post the solution as an answer.

Comment: I solved: first line `TiXmlElement* e = hDoc.FirstChildElement().FirstChildElement().Element();` get count of <states>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you read the [documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlNode.html) you can find the following example (which seems neater than your approach):

```
for( child = parent->FirstChild(); child; child = child->NextSibling() )
    count++;
```

But you are probably only trying to count the states so I would suggest:

```cpp
for( child = parent->FirstChild("state"); child; child = child->NextSibling("state") )
```

You probably also want something like this:

```
TiXmlElement *parent = hDoc.RootElement();
```